# Default directory when using WorkingDirectory when using ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

What is the default directory for WorkingDirectory if it is not defined when using ProcessStartInfo?

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"cscript.exe";

//startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\NotDefined";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `startInfo.WorkingDirectory` property to set it.

If the property is not set, the default working directory is `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32`.

Answer (score 2):

The `WorkingDirectory`, if not set, will be the default %SystemRoot%\system32.

The function of the property depends however on the `UseShellExecute` flag:

> **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)**:
>   When the UseShellExecute property is *false*, gets or sets the working directory for the process to be started.
>   When UseShellExecute is *true*, gets or sets the directory that contains the process to be started.